# Is .NET project architecture by domain functionality is a good and viable practice?

Tags: .net, architecture, project-organization

I am implementing the application consisting of SOA WCF microservices and ASP.NET MVC web-client, and cannot choose between the following projects organizations:

**1. By layers \ types**

All projects models, enums, services etc. are stored in separate projects, no matter which functionality they belong to.

```
Solution
+ Domain
++ Models
  - User.cs
  - Payment.cs
  - Bookmark.cs
++ Repository
  - UserRepository.cs
  - PaymentRepository.cs
  - BookmarkRepository.cs
++ Enums
  - UserType.cs
  - PaymentStatus.cs
++ Services
  - IUserService.cs
  - IPaymentService.cs
  - IBookmarkService.cs
  - UserService.cs
  - PaymentService.cs
  - BookmarkService.cs
```

**2. By domain functionality**

Every project represents a single independent *(sometimes, partly dependent)* functionality, including all necessary models, repositories, services, business logics etc.

```
Solution
+ Domain
++ Authentication
  - User.cs
  - UserType.cs
  - IUserService.cs
  - UserService.cs
  - UserRepository.cs
++ Payments
  - Payment.cs
  - PaymentStatus.cs
  - IPaymentService.cs
  - PaymentService.cs
  - PaymentRepository.cs
++ Bookmarks
  - Bookmark.cs
  - IBookmarkService.cs
  - BookmarkService.cs  
  - BookmarkRepository.cs
```

I have always been using the first approach, but the second one looks good for me because:
 - These directories like `Models`, `Enums` grow up to 50-100 classes with time and it becomes inconvenient
 - If you implement an application which works only one functionality, then you have to reference the whole huge project with all models, types and services
 - The second approach allows you to easily introduce / remove / change
   any functionality
 - When separated by domain, code looks more reusable

However, this approach can cause problems when there are circular dependencies while the first one does not. For example, when `User` has a property of type `Bookmark`, and `Bookmark` has a property of type `User`.
Also, actually functionalities do rely on each other and these "borders" can be pretty ambiguous.
Probably, there are even other drawbacks, which I cannot see, and which will become an architecture flaw in future.

Is the second project organization viable?
Do people use the second approach at all?

Comment: I'd say this boils down to opinion, and it maybe even depends on the specific project. If I have to comment on something, I think having a separate project for *just* enums is weird, and I'd put them with the rest of the models.

Comment: Second approach. Feature folders make it much easier to understand an individual feaure as described in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

When was the last time you wanted to see all enums, all repositories, all models at once? This almost never happens. It is much more common to want to inspect a particular feature in its entirety.

It's a common mistake to cluster code by some arbitrary criterion that is not actually being used to *find something*.

Cluster your code by something that you want to search for. Here, use the feature-based classification.

Further, I don't think this is a matter of taste. The only reason to cluster similar code together is to optimize lookups. So choose the clustering to match what you are searching for.

> For example, when User has a property of type Bookmark, and Bookmark has a property of type User. Also, actually functionalities do rely on each other and these "borders" can be pretty ambiguous.

If you have that problem this is a sign that this is not a good split boundary. Maybe you don't need to split at all?! Splitting code into separate projects has costs and benefits. You need to be able to formulate a clear understanding of both sides. What benefit are you going to derive from splitting into projects? Wouldn't namespaces and folders achieve almost the same thing? (I can't know the answer in your case.)